# Using MICE for Growth Curve Model

Tags: r, r-mice, mlm

I used MICE to impute data, and now I am trying to do growth curve modeling. I'm in the stage of assessing if there is a need for multlivevel modelling Here is my code

```
ICept <-gls(edeqGLOBAL_mean ~ 1, data=Imputed, method = "ML", na.action=na.exclude)
RICept <-lme(edeqGLOBAL_mean ~ 1, data=Imputed, random=~1|ID, method = "ML", na.actioin=na.exclude, control=c(optim="optim"))
```

and this is the error message I am getting

> Error in as.data.frame.default(data, optional = TRUE) : cannot coerce class ‘"mids"’ to a data.frame

Any help as to what to do?

Answer (score 1):

First of all, you need to understand what multiple imputation means: It creates several imputation for each missing value. Therefore, the `mids` object is essentially a list of data frames that have slightly different imputations for the missing values. The variance between these imputations represents your uncertainty about the missing data.

Because `mids` is not just a `data.frame`, you cannot use it the same way. Analyzing multiple imputation data involves two steps: First apply the analysis to each imputed data set. Second aggregate the results (i.e. model coefficients etc.) according to [Rubin's rules](https://bookdown.org/mwheymans/bookmi/rubins-rules.html) such that you get an overall estimate as well as standard errors that include the variance between imputations.

For several statistical functions (e.g. `ml`, `glm`, `anova`), the `mice` package provides an easy implementation of these two steps. A simple linear regression, for instance can be conducted on a `mids` object like this:

```
lm1_mira <- with(mydata_mids, lm(y ~ x1 + x2)) #with.mids() creates a `mira` object
pool(lm1_mira)
```

Now, for `nlme::lme()` and `gls()` these methods are not readily implemented. You will have to do a bit of programming instead. Specifically your code should involve the following:

1. Create a function that conducts your analysis and outputs the relevant coefficients/estimates and their standard errors. This may look *something like* this:
   `ICept_fun <- function(dat) summary(gls(edeqGLOBAL_mean ~ 1, method="ML", data=dat))$coefficients`
2. Apply the function to each imputed dataset.
   a. Extract datasets from the `mids` object:
   `Imputed_list <- lapply(1:Imputed$m, function(i) complete(Imputed, action=i))`
   b. Apply function:
   `ICept_list <- lapply(Imputed_list, ICept_fun)`
3. Pool the results using the `pool.scalar`-function from `mice`. It is meant for pooling any normally distributed (!) statistic that you calculated from a multiply imputed dataset. This also  means that you may have to transform some of your statistics of interest before you can apply `pool.scalar` and back-transform them afterwards. For example, correlations should be transformed to Fisher's Z. Please see [this useful vignette](https://www.gerkovink.com/miceVignettes/Combining_inferences/Combining_inferences.html) if you are not sure about your statistics of interest.
   The `pool.scalar()` function wants vectors of estimates (argument `Q`) and respective variances (argument `U`), so you need to reshape the list of results a bit. This may or may not look like this - depending on your function `ICept_fun`:
   `ICept_Qs <- lapply(ICept_list, function(x) x["(Intercept)", 1])`
   `ICept_Us <- lapply(ICept_list, function(x) x["(Intercept)", 2]^2) #squared SE for variance estimate`

***If it turns out you need multilevel modelling, please be aware:***
Multiple imputation of multilevel data brings its very own additional problems. In the imputation itself, you should take the multilevel structure of the data into account. If you just applied `mice::mice()` to your (long-format) dataset, this is *not* correct. One alternative method is to make a wide-format dataset, conduct multiple imputation, and then reshape the resulting imputed datasets back to long-format. In this case, back-shaping to long format would take place between the steps 2a and 2b that described above. As to whether this is the preferred method, I do not know. There are some good sources about this, for instance [this vignette](https://www.gerkovink.com/miceVignettes/Multi_level/Multi_level_data.html).